# Top x% labels missing on some user profiles

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-leagues

On [some user profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael), there is a "top x%" label:

[image]

But this is not shown for some users:

[image]

Why is that so? I don't see any settings to hide this.

Comment: Yeah, same here on MSE. Most users, including top users, don't have the label anymore.

Comment: Using any userscripts? I see it just fine, it's just using all time instead of this month: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKBX1.png If not, can you let us know what browser/version/OS?

Comment: @Catija I see it now too, but didn't before. Might have been temporary glitch that was "fixed" on its own. Let's see what OP says.

Comment: @Catija Just tested it on various environments (macOS, Windows, Chrome, Firefox, Safari), none of them is showing the label for Jon Skeet.

Comment: [I'm also able to see Jon Skeet's ranking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KG2A.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

After the little investigation I noticed that if the “top x%” label is missing on the user profile page:

> [image: no top]

Visiting the activity tab and going back to the profile tab fix the issue:

> [image: top]

Seems there is some kind of caching.